# Migrating users from windows server 2008r2 to web edition

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I am trying to find a way to migrate local users from a Win2008r2 server to Win2008r2 web edition. It seems the migration feature is not available there.

Are there any other tools that would help with this?

Comment: I'm curious, does this guide not work for you with Web Edition? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd379531(WS.10).aspx#BKMK_strategy

Comment: no, MIgration feature cannot be installed on web edition. as far as I can tell.

Comment: Ah, somehow I missed the line on that page: "Foundation, Standard, Enterprise, and Datacenter editions of Windows Server are supported as either source or destination servers."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can purchase something like [SecureCopy](http://www.scriptlogic.com/products/securecopy/) which claims to be able to do this, but AFAIK there is no official Microsoft tool to do this.

You could always just export a list of users by running `net user > list.txt` and then make sure you re-create all of those users on the new server.